# Minimum spanning tree of multi directed graph

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs, minimum-spanning-tree, spanning-trees

I have problem of inferring a rooted tree out of a connected simple graph.

The inference can be done by finding its minimum spanning tree, but the result is restricted by additional two types of condition:

- There is a known root, which is `s` in the following example.
- We know directions of some edges **if they are chosen**. These edges are **not** chosen yet, or the problem becomes a Steiner tree problem.

Note that numbers on edges are their weights. So we will get `s -> b -> c -> a` if a normal min spanning tree is applied, but the direction of edge `ac` is wrong. On the other hand, we cannot use Chu–Liu/Edmonds' algorithm for spanning arborescence of directed graphs, because we don't know and cannot infer the direction of edge `bc`.

[image]

We can infer some edges' directions according to the position of the root. For example, in the example, we know `s -> b` and `s -> a`.

**It seems that the problem can be solved by two steps**:

1. turn the simple graph into a multi-graph. For edges (in the original simple graph) whose directions are unknown, we represent them in a multi-graph using two directed edges between two vertices with inverse directions.
2. We find the minimum oriented spanning tree of this multi-graph.

---

### Oriented Spanning Tree

In the final section of [spanning tree, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree), oriented spanning tree is mentioned and a paper [levine2011sandpile] is referred. The problem fits the setting. It says:

> Given a vertex `v` on a directed multigraph `G`, an oriented spanning tree `T` rooted at `v` is an acyclic subgraph of `G` in which every vertex other than `v` has outdegree 1.

*Note that the term "outdegree" is a bit confusing, which I think should be "indegree". But it doesn't matter, because it just restricts the simple subgraph to be a directed tree with root being source or sink.*

But it is not clear to me how an algorithm can be implemented according to that paper.

---

- Levine, L. (2011). Sandpile groups and spanning trees of directed line graphs. Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A, 118(2), 350-364.
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree

Comment: Can you please clarify your problem? I'm not sure I understand the problem you described in the first part of your question, and how it relates to the definition of an oriented spanning tree in the second part of your question. IIRC the definition of a directed multigraph usually has the undirected edges represent two connected edges in opposite directions. Is that the case here? In this case, I'm almost certain what you want is exactly the min-cost arborescence algorithm.

Comment: Also, by "if they are chosen" do you mean once we decide to include the edge in the algorithm, its direction will "magically" be specified via an oracle? If that's the case then we can just trivially query for all edges' directions first in $O(|E|)$-time and then use the min-cost arboresence algorithm.

Comment: After the "if they are chosen" part, I missed a `not`.

Comment: I know the direction according to other information. The resulted rooted tree should not violate these information.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I think we are talking about the same thing. As for the min-cost arborescence algorithm you mentioned, I found [minimum_spanning_arborescence in `networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.tree.branchings.minimum_spanning_arborescence.html#networkx.algorithms.tree.branchings.minimum_spanning_arborescence) works for directed multi-graph. It works for this example. I saw the authors are discussing it as well in [#3825](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/3825).

Comment: We operate differently than discussion forums you might be used to.  Please don't edit the question to add "SOLVED" to it.  Instead, write your own answer that describes the solution in detail, in the 'Your Answer' box below.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. Have posted an answer. But I think it's better to have the title corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by the comments, this is a minimum spanning tree problem, which can be solved efficiently by Edmonds' algorithm (or Chu–Liu/Edmonds' algorithm).